# I need to fill the cache(CacheBuilder) as it starts. Is there any random way to do it?

Tags: java, caching, insert, buffer

I have a batch program that uses a cache. Initially the cache is empty, as soon as the data arrives
It Compares the received data with the previous received data. 
     * - If data  not found: added to data 
     * - If data found but different: update the data 
     * - If data found but same: data filtered out

So, after few time, the cache size increases as the data keep on increasing. and there the processing is taking quite a amount of time to process.

I need to test this whole situation, and I have a few incoming data and I need to regenerate this situation. So I need to fill the cache as it starts. Is there any random way to do it?

I am using CacheBuilder for the cache:

private Cache> statesCache = .newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build();

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  What's stopping you from "filling the cache as it starts"?

Comment: I thought, there will be some inbuilt function to do that. Later I did it using for loop.

Comment: You just found the "inbuilt function to do that." It's how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought, there will be some inbuilt function to do that. Later I did it using for loop:

private static Cache> statesCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()//
            .maximumSize(1000).expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).build();

```
static {

    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        Map<String, State> map = new HashMap<String, State>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            State randomState = new State() {
                String VALUE = null;
                String Id = null;
                String DATA = null;

                @Override
                public void setVALUE(String VALUE) {
                    this.VALUE = VALUE;

                }

                @Override
                public void setId(String Id) {
                    this.Id = Id;

                }

                @Override
                public void setDATA(String DATA) {
                    this.DATA = DATA;

                }

                @Override
                public String getVALUE() {
                    return VALUE;
                }

                @Override
                public String getId() {
                    return Id;
                }

                @Override
                public String getDATA() {
                    return DATA;
                }

            };

            randomState.setDATA("Data_" + j);
            randomState.setId("Id_" + j);
            randomState.setVALUE("Value_" + j);
            map.put("Id_" + j, randomState);
        }
        statesCache.put("BSTN_" + String.format("%04d", i), map);
    }
}
```